# Accidentally overwrote .classpath file when exporting project on eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, classpath, eclipse-classpath

I've been pushing and pulling projects from git and importing them into my eclipse workspace.

I tried exporting my project and I got an error (something about overwriting .classpath file) and I chose to proceed.Now I can't open my project(class path not in class file error) and I can't push anything into gitlab anymore because they will notify no changes have been made even if I modified the code.

What my Eclipse workspace looks like:

[image: What my Eclipse workspace looks like]

I googled, apparently you can re-generate .classpath files? If it helps I did save a copy of the overwritten .classpath file.

Comment: Is it still a Java project (blue project folder icon decorated with 'J') or did you also overwrite the `.project` file?

Comment: It's still a java project

Comment: What happens if you copy the backup of the `.classpath` file into the project directory? Use the _Navigator_ instead of the _Package Explorer_ view to be able to see files starting with a dot. You can recreate the `.classpath` file by creating a new Java project.

Comment: I found the .classpath file so how do I copy paste the old one into the project directory

Comment: Ok I copy pasted it but nothing happens?

Comment: Please add the content of your `.classpath` file to your question.